# Hide a set of image when clicking on a radio button in pure CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to hide/show a set of images when a radio button is on/off in pure CSS.

There are 4 radio buttons like this one (with 2nd set, etc) :

```
<input type="radio" name="imagetest" id="firstSet"><label for="firstSet" id="firstSet">First Set</label>
```

I've put just below those radio buttons a set of images in a div:

```
<div id="images">
<img src="images/01.jpg" class="firstset">
<img src="images/02.jpg" class="firstset">
<img src="images/03.jpg" class="secondset">
<img src="images/04.jpg" class="secondset">
<img src="images/05.jpg" class="thirdset">
<img src="images/06.jpg" class="firstset">
</div>
```

Having some clues from old threads from stackoverflow, I defined my CSS like this :

```
input#firstSet:checked ~ .firstset {
display: block;
}
input#secondSet:checked ~ .firstset, input#thirdSet:checked ~ .firstset {
display: none;
}
```

However it doesn't work at all, nothing is appearing/hiding as intended.

Would anyone have any clues on how to fix this problem ?

Thanks,
Seb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
input#firstSet:checked ~ #images > .firstset {
display: block;
}
input#secondSet:checked ~ #images > .firstset, input#thirdSet:checked ~ .firstset {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="imagetest" id="firstSet"><label for="firstSet" id="firstSet">First Set</label>
<div id="images">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e0/JPEG_example_JPG_RIP_050.jpg" class="firstset">
<img src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/1637/file_icons_vs_2/256/jpg.png" class="firstset">
<img src="http://www.iconarchive.com/download/i93939/uiconstock/flat-file-type/jpg.ico" class="secondset">
<img src="https://media.alienwarearena.com/media/tux-r.jpg" class="secondset">
<img src="https://media.alienwarearena.com/media/tux-r.jpg" class="thirdset">
<img src="https://media.alienwarearena.com/media/tux-r.jpg" class="firstset">
</div>
```